# How can I add a bigger margin around my button?

Tags: android, button

I have these two buttons in my program, one has a good fat margin of blue around, the other one however doesn't. The words are right on the border of the button, how can I add some margin?

[image: Here]

Comment: can you put your layout xml please. Maybe you need set some padding for the right button.

Comment: It's a combination of the text being too long and the surrounding layout that is causing the right button to be "squished"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you are looking for is `padding`. In your Android xml add the `padding` property for the button. Something like

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

You can adjust the number and see whatever suits you.

Comment: Haha yeah sorry kinda new to this.. but thanks for the advice! really helped

Answer (score 0):

Use padding for both button. Like this

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Add padding value for the right button like this

```
android:paddingLeft="12dp"
android:paddingRight="12dp"
```